# Returning complex objects in custom WCF 3.5 Service hosted in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint-2010

I have been able to deploy a custom WCF 3.5 service written in c# to SharePoint 2010, and return simple type values no problem. As soon as I try to return a complex object, after re-deploying the service, I get a 404 error when I try to hit it.

I have followed the tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581(v=office.14).aspx.

I have also tried removing the Factory directive in the .svc file and defining my own web.config in the ISAPI mapped folder with basicHttp, webHttp, and mex bindings to no avail.

My complex object is decorated with [DataContract] on the class and [DataMember] on all properties. Two of its properties are complex types themselves, and I have included the knowntype directive for these types above the class name as well.

What am I doing wrong? What are the rules for returning complex types in WCF 3.5 in SharePoint? I have been able to return complex types for WCF 4 outside of SharePoint using multiple bindings.

Comment: Any ideas? Should this work the way I'm describing it?